# MAT 2019 Question $2$- Coefficients of polynomials and their degrees

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> For $k$ is a positive integer, we define the polynomial $p_k(x)$ as$$p_k(x) = (1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)\cdot \ldots (1+x^k) = a_0 + a_1x+ \ldots a_N x^N$$
>   denoting the coefficients of $p_k(x)$ as $a_0,\ldots,a_N$
>   $i)$ By setting $x=1$, or otherwise, explain why 
>   $$a_{\text{max}} \ge \frac{2^k}{N+1}$$
>   where $a_{\text{max}}$ denotes the largest of the coefficients $a_0,\ldots a_N.$

I started solving by first finding the degree $N$ in terms of $k$, this is simply $$\sum ^k _1 n = \frac{(k)(k+1)}{2}$$ 
Then put this in the equation to see that $$a_{\text{max}} \ge \frac{2^k}{\frac{(k)(k+1)}{2}+1}$$ This gives us, $$a_{\text{max}} \ge \frac{2^{k+1}}{k^2+k+2}$$  But this isn't really anything very useful, any advice on how to go from here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $x=1$. If the sum of $N+1$ numbers is $2^{k}$ the at least one of them must be $\geq \frac {2^{k}} {N+1}$. To see this prove by contradiction. If each of the numbers is less than $\frac {2^{k}} {N+1}$ what happens to the sum?

Comment: And the only other way that the sum can be $2^k$ is if all are equal to $\frac{2^k}{N+1}$ which is clearly not the case. Damn proof by contradiction very smart +1 upvote!

Comment: @PrakharNagpal Yes the bound is easily improved: For $k\ge5$, $p_k(x)=1+x+x^2+2x^3+\cdots +2x^{N-3}+x^{N-2}+x^{N-1}+x^N$, so that $\max\{a_4,\ldots, a_{N-4}\}\ge\frac{a_4+\cdots+a_{N-4}}{N-7}=\frac{p_k(1)-10}{N-7}=\frac{2^k-10}{N-7}$, for example

Answer (score 1):

$p_{k}(1)=a_{0}+a_{1}+\cdots+a_{N}\leq a_{M}+a_{M}+\cdots+a_{M}=(N+1)a_{M}$. But $p_{k}(1)=2^{k}$ by direct plugging.